# repairing mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

We were running out of the disk space on slave  because of relay-bin files, so  I stopped the mysql server, deleted the  relay-bin files.  changed my.cnf file to point the relay log to another location.   In Slave status, I noted the 'Relay_Master_Log_File' and 'Exec_Master_Log_Position'. I used them to 'Change Master'. It doesn't work.
I get at the prompt, It says Failed to open the relay-log at the old position.  How Mysql is still looking at the old files, and how I can change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should have originally deleted the logs by issuing `RESET SLAVE`.

Still, if you:

- Are happy with the consistency of the slave's data to-date.
- You have a record of `Exec_Master_Log_Position` and the corresponding log filename.
- The master still has the logs which correspond to this log position and filename.

Issue `STOP SLAVE` and `RESET SLAVE`. This will remove all replication related information from the slave including `relay-log.info` which is likely to be causing the error you see.

Use `CHANGE MASTER ..` to reconfigure the slave with your log position, host, username, etc.

Then kick it back up with `START SLAVE`.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working right away, your best bet may be to :
mysqldump --master-data --databases db_name > snapshot20091124.sql and scp it over to your replication slave.  You can double check the log position by paging through the first few lines of the mysql dump.  issue a "stop slave;" , do an import "mysql -u root -p < snapshot20091124.sql", then issue a "start slave".  Replication is a sometimes needlessly complicated beast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your slave server to flush out the cache.